# Communicating Data Between PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, textbox

I'm making a website to show the contents of a file when a link is clicked, and I know that PHP cannot handle local actions, but JS can. But sadly, I cannot think of a feasible way to communicate say... a variable named `$fileContents` between them.
What I need is to pass the variable `$fileContents` somehow from PHP to JS and have JS print the text into a textbox.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the good way to do this in my opinion is using ajax, create a function that will request the file from the server, then append the response to a div on the page or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually about "passing" a variable from PHP to JavaScript.

**Remember that :**

- PHP is a server-side scripting language
- JavaScript resides on a client's browser.

So, you could actually... write directly any javascript you wish from your PHP script.

Let's say, you've got a `$a` variable... then you could simply enter it in your javascript code like this :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     var a = <?php echo $a; ?>
</script>
```

**However :**

If what you mean is to actually use the `$a` var while the page has loaded, or retrieve the result in some way, WITHOUT reloading, then what you probably need is Ajax.

To use AJAX, I would either suggest :

- the jQuery `load` method
- using some [ready-made AJAX object](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Ultimate_Ajax_Object)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to Google for something called "AJAX" and perhaps something called "JQuery", to keep it easy.